# Hibernate JoinTableFilter annotation

Tags: spring, hibernate, join, hibernate-mapping

I'm using Hibernate to map my entities and I'm having a problem. I want my entity to retrieve a list of entity from another table, linked with a join table. I also want to filter on the join table to only retrieve objets whose boolean_value is set to false.
It currently works without filtering, using @JoinTable annotation. I'm facing difficulties when it comes about @FilterJoinTable which seems not to be working.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "table_a")
@FilterDef(name="checkValue")
@Filter(name = "checkValue")
public class AEntity {
    // id ...

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "my_join_table",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id"))
    @FilterJoinTable(name = "checkValue", condition = "boolean_value = FALSE")
    private List<BEntity> objets;

}
```

[image: Quick representation of my tables]

Currently it returns all the objects from table_b without filtering.

Any idea of what I'm doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `@Where` annotation, as `@FilterJoinTable` allows defining Hibernate filters which have to be enabled explicitly with `Session#enableFilter(String)`:

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "my_join_table",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "a_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "b_id"))
@Where(clause = "boolean_value = FALSE")
private List<BEntity> objets;
```